# TabHost Tabs Not Populating the ListView

Tags: android

I have three tabs and the first one is where the ListView should show up. I wanted to keep my code clean so I structure my app like this:

TabContainer: This contains the tabs and this hosts all the tab items 
Activity1: ListView activity 
Activity2: . another activity

The small part of tabContainer looks like this:

```
   <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabVegetables"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/vegetable_list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/activity_vegetable_list" >
                    </include>


                    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see that I am including a layout "activity_vegetable_list" which is where the ListView resides. I put a break point in the onCreate method in the VegetableListActivity and that is never hit. Any ideas why the onCreate method of the VegetableListActivity which is the java class for activity_vegetable_list layout not invoked.

**VegetableListActivity.java:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vegetable_list);

        // set the title
        setTitle("Vegetable Tree");
        populateVegetables();

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.someapp.app.Activities.TabContainerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_container" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: Can you post code for the VegetableListActivity?

Comment: I updated the code but it does not step into the onCreate method in the debugger.

Comment: Can you double check your AndroidManifest.xml file to see what the launcher Activity is?

Comment: Launcher activity is tabContainer (see updated question). The app runs fine but displays nothing for the content for the tab. It should show list view.